# Using AngularJS for generating repeatable HTML blocks without directives

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, angularjs-directive

Let's say that I have list of elements that I need to display. HTML I have is much more complex but for brevity of example let's use this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="centered">
            <a href="#"><img src="/assets/img/icons/facebook.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="centered">
            <a href="#"><img src="/assets/img/icons/twitter.png" width="25" height="25" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="centered">
            <a href="#"><img src="/assets/img/icons/google.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, obviously duplicating HTML is a problem... and that can be solved by creating angular directive and redoing previous HTML snippet:

```
<ul>
    <my-li-directive icon="facebook.png" width="50" height="50">
    <my-li-directive icon="twitter.png" width="25" height="25">
    <my-li-directive icon="google.png" width="30" height="30">
</ul>
```

The problem with this is that in order to make it happen I need to create 2 more extra files - myLiDirective.js & myLiDirective.html.

I get this approach if I will be using my-li-directive in multiple pages, but in this specific case I am aiming for just removing duplicate HTML. And what I get if I use AngularJs directive is that I somewhat increase complexity - more files, another HTTP request if I don't bundle myLiDirective.html, etc - problems that are solvable, but problems anyway.

So, instead of doing directive, can I do something like:

```
<script>
    var loginButtons = [
        {icon: "facebook.png", width:50, height:50},
        {icon: "twitter.png", width:25, height:25},
        {icon: "google.png", width:30, height:30}
    ]
</script>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="btn in loginButtons">
        <div class="centered">
            <a href="#"><img src="/assets/img/icons/{{btn.icon}}" width="{{btn.width}}" height="{{btn.height}}" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I understand that this is somewhat unorthodox approach - but would I lose anything with it? It definitely makes HTML much more readable and maintainable, plus everything is in one place/file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is actually perfect situation to use ASP.NET Razor:

```
@{
    var loginButtons = new [] {
        new {icon="facebook.png", width=50, height=50},
        new {icon="twitter.png", width=25, height=25},
        new {icon="google.png", width=30, height=30}
    };
}
<ul>
    @foreach (var btn in loginButtons) {
        <li ng-repeat="btn in loginButtons">
            <div class="centered">
                <a href="#"><img src="/assets/img/icons/@btn.icon" width="@btn.width" height="@btn.height" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of opitionated question, but you won't lose anything.

Directives are pretty useful to build more "component-like" structures and have a controller for each instance and all of that. But, it seems like you don't need any of that, you just want code replication in a pretty way, so it solves your problem. You won't lose anything with it.

The only downside is that your controller (where you store your info for each list item) will store an array and to take an action on a single item, you'll have to make a search to find the right object - and even that can be avoided - instead of an directive with an associated controller, where the code for functions would be more readable (just a little).

Anyways, I think this doesn't break any Angular best practice scenario =)

Comment: Yeah - you actually nailed the biggest problem I have - if I don't introduce directive I need to hold that data array in controller's scope. Global javascript variable doesn't sound good to me - but it is the only approach that keeps that array close to that HTML template (which is what I am aiming for).

Comment: Why? I mean, you could store them in an Angular Controller scope and use it like you are, your html gets even cleaner!

If you add it in a controller you are already using (I'm assuming you are using some controller in that page =P), you don't need to create any file nor make any new requests!

Comment: I don't want to move that array to controller's scope because it doesn't "belong" there. Plus, I want [variable declared as close as possible to place of their usage](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/56585/where-do-you-declare-variables-the-top-of-a-method-or-when-you-need-them). Seems like what I am doing is definitely best done server side.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to introduce 2 extra files, it's possible to simply write the template html in a directive as well, and while it might be opinionated, I think it's preferable to write it directly in a directive instead of creating extra html files if the html is small and belongs to a larger layout.

Also, you don't need to create a new directive file, just include it in the bigger part of the layout file it is used in (unless you have that particular banner template in different places in your site, in that case it is still better to use a directive as you want to aim for DRY).

In your html it will simply look like

```
<my-banner-directive>
```

, which is pretty nice if it's repeated in different places, 
then in your directive write out the template and all the information contained within it. I think it's more concise and clean, than to have to repeat it multiple times, you also avoid cluttering the controllers if you have it in different places as they should preferably be as minimal as possible.

With all that said, if it is a small part used in only one part of the layout, nothing wrong with having a special solution, like you have it now!